# Cursor moving about at random

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, cursor

How can I regain control of a randomly moving cursor which seems to have a mind of its own. It jumps to a new screen position at random resulting in my typing 'inserting' itself where it should not be etc. It will also jump and activate a link. It is not OS specific as it happens on my two computers (Windows 7 and Windows XP). I have cleaned/changed the mouse and also changed the mouse pad to no effect. HELP.

Comment: You originally posted this on [Security.SE]. Is there a reason to assume this is a virus (on both computers)? What do your virus scanners say?

Comment: My guess - Hitting the touchpad while typing.  Or perhaps the wrong touchpad driver.

Answer (score 1):

I had this in the past with a wireless keyboard and mouse combo.

The key thing was I was not using the wireless mouse only the keyboard and got very strange behaviour, the fix was to have the mouse in a draw close enough that the signal could be detected.

This was about seven years ago and the manufacture was Belkin.

I guess the lack of signal from the mouse forced the receiver to seek out any signal that "should" be the mouse and ended up with essentially static.